# Android studio gets hanged at splash screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have installed android studio in windows10 as well installed jdk the installation process has gone smoothly but when the android studio opens it just stuck with the splash screen itself.

I have added the environment variable for the jdk but even it didn't works.The versions which i am using are as follows
JDK version is 1.8.0_101 and android studio version is 2.1 and i am using it in windows 10 and the path of the android studio is C:\Program Files.

Even i have ended the task in taskmanger and restarted mypc and opened android studio but it didn't works.Even i have uninstalled android studio and installed it again and run it as admin but even it shows the splash screen only.

[image: Hanged splash screen]

Comment: What is your RAM size?

Comment: it is 4gb ram and i3 processor

Comment: kill all other apps from task manager and try to open studio,because studio use almost 3.75 gb ram while booting.

Comment: but it didn't works

Answer (score 1):

You should have a proper Internet Connection while installing Android Studio. The studio  needs a lot of file from net after installing. And try Deleting all files related to android from your c drive . Try installing now. Also dont forget Restart your PC after Uninstalling..  & try Updating Java files Too ..
Good Luck ..

Answer (score 0):

Install again on different drive by deleting its loading and configuration files from AppData hidden folder too and also also given path.

path `C:\Users\Sohail Zahid\.AndroidStudio2.1`